# Why I getting natural width 0 for dynamically created image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, face-detection, webcam.js

I am using [Webcam.js](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) for getting images form camera.

`document.getElementById('cameraImage').src = data_uri;`  data_uri gives me the image form capture event of camera.

Then I create Image dynamically in JavaScript like
var img = new Image();
img.src = data_uri;

When I am trying to apply face detection on it using [Facedetection.js](https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection)
it gives error Failed to execute getImageData on CanvasRenderingContext2D: The source width is 0.

How can i set source width of image so face detection will work

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific for Facedetection js do one modification so your porblem will get solved.

In facedetection.js you will find

grayscale(image){    }
 function

Change the following canvas width and height setting

```
canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
```

Your face detection will start working properly

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur for security reasons if you are trying to load images from other server.

Please follow this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image .

Check if you see an image after creating it. Test is simple:

```
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = data_uri;
document.body.appendChild(newImg);
```

Comment: This problem is caused when I am using Camera for getting image as well as when I am upload image from user too.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a data URI as an image source is an async operation. Make sure your image is fully loaded before you try to do anything else with it:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    // Call your face detection methods here...
}
img.src = data_uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when using an image from server file ( load more slow than local file ). This my fix ( from line number about 16568 ):

```
if (time = new Date().getTime(), $$.is("img")) {
                            source = new Image(), source.src = $$.attr("src"),
                                    source.crossOrigin = $$.attr("crossorigin");

                            $(source).load(function () {
                                canvas = ccv.pre(source);
                                options.grayscale && (canvas = ccv.grayscale(canvas, source));
                                try {
                                    options.async && window.Worker ? ccv.detect_objects({
                                        canvas: canvas,
                                        cascade: cascade,
                                        interval: options.interval,
                                        min_neighbors: options.minNeighbors,
                                        worker: 1,
                                        async: !0
                                    })(done) : done(ccv.detect_objects({
                                        canvas: canvas,
                                        cascade: cascade,
                                        interval: options.interval,
                                        min_neighbors: options.minNeighbors
                                    }));
                                } catch (e) {
                                    options.error.apply($$, [2, e.message]), options.complete.apply($$, [!1]);
                                }
                            });
                            return this;

                        }
```